# Create Stored Procedure using stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Trying to create a new stored procedure using another stored procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CreateNewDB]
@dbName nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
EXEC('CREATE DATABASE '+@dbName)
EXEC('USE '+@dbName+ ' CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_GetUser] 
        @id varchar(50)
        AS
        BEGIN
        <<Stored Procedure Logic>>
        END')
END
```

When I try to call the above stored procedure as below

```
DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[CreateNewDB]
        @dbName = N'MyUserDatabase'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
```

It creates the database not the stored procedure.

It throws the following error.

```
Msg 111, Level 15, State 1, Procedure usp_GetUser, Line 6
'CREATE/ALTER PROCEDURE' must be the first statement in a query batch.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GO` can not be used in a dynamic sql. You could use a nested sql query like this

```
DECLARE @dbName nvarchar(30) = 'abcxys'

DECLARE @query nvarchar(max) = 'USE ' + Quotename(@dbName) + 
      '; EXEC sp_executesql N''' + N'CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_GetUser] 
      @id varchar(50)
      AS
      BEGIN
         select 1
      END' + ''''; 

PRINT @query

EXEC (@query)
```

Answer (score 0):

I split up the go's and run it with the same connection, staying open while they're running. It creates the stored procedure from the file I get from the directory.

```
public void RunSprocFile(string sprocFileName, DbContext db)
    {
        try
        {
            var sprocFileSplit = GetSprocFromFile(sprocFileName).Split(new[] {"GO"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            _connectionManager.OpenConn(db);
            foreach (var t in sprocFileSplit)
                if (t.Trim().Length > 0)
                    RunSql(t, db);
            _connectionManager.CloseConn(db);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            RecordException(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: FYI, when you have a group of people trying to help you, and you yank the question out from under us while we're typing lengthy comments to help you, it doesn't encourage us to help you in the future. We wasted our time.

Comment: I got two down vote right off the bat. WTF? I'm trying to learn. I looked for a long time and the one comment did help me, so thank you. I'm sorry, but apparently it was a stupid question and at least two people make sure to hit my points. Apparently I wasted my own time as well and I shouldn't ask any questions anymore.